# Getting errors in pom.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, resteasy

I need help because I have no experience using Maven. I am trying to run this sample application a tutorial for is here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/restful-web-services-with-resteasy-jax.html

I have edited the pom.xml as stated in the tutorial, but Iam getting these errors:

- Missing artifact javax.servlet-api:jar.2.5:provided
- Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jettison-provider:
- missing artifact junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
- missing artifact javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
  etc...

They all are kind of dependency errors, but since I have no idea how to use Maven I don't know how to solve them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JBoss has changed the location of the maven repository so change `<url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/</url>` in the repository element to `<url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>`

JBoss often changes their repositoy so it gets really confused since there are so many urls on the internet (even their own documentation are worng) but most of them don't work.